# Box object not centered on my mouse

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxNjy.png)I'm trying out some Java Game dev, so far i've created a box that can move with key input, now im trying mouse input. I have a few questions...

1. I'm using a class called MouseInput which implements MouseMotionListener, is this the right way to get mouse co-ords?
2. My box follows my mouse but on a huge offset, what do you think the problem may be?

Here is the code for the mouse input event:

```
 @Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

    for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++) {
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if (tempObject.getId()==ID.Player) {

            tempObject.setX(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x);
            tempObject.setY(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y);
        }
    }
}
```

The image attached shows the box, my mouse is located in the top left 0,0.

Comment: 1) Mouse event has also the coordinates (relativ to the object which is the originator of the event), so it's better to use it. But in some cases (when you need screen coordinates) you can also use the class `MouseInfo`. 2) This question cannot be answered until we get a short runnable example of your problem ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)), so we can also run and debug it. Probably you simply need to call the `revalidate()` and `repaint()` methods on your main panel (`tempObject.getParent().repaint()`).

Comment: I managed to solve this problem by creating 2 variables, mPosX = e.get() and mPosY = e.getY() and then set the tempObject to those locations, is there a reason why this works? if you know, thank you

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: `My box follows my mouse but on a huge offset` What is the offset you get and X and Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

    mPosX = e.getX();
    mPosY = e.getY();

    System.out.println(mPosX + ", " + mPosY);

    for (int i = 0; i<handler.object.size(); i++){
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if (tempObject.getId() == ID.Player){
            tempObject.setX(mPosX);
            tempObject.setY(mPosY);
        }
    }
    e.consume();
}
```

This code here seems to solve the problem, however, I am not entirely sure why.

Comment: The MouseInfo class gives you the mouse location relative to the screen. Unless your panel containing the object is located at (0, 0) you will always have an offset. When you use the values from the MouseEvent, the points are now relative to the component you added the MouseMotionListener to.